# How to create spec for model scope method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec

I have scope method in Assessment model, which I call in AssessmentsController on the collection of assessments, but I can't create test for this method, because:
1) in response I don't get `risk_value`, but in controller (`@assessments.with_assessment_progresses(@customer_id)`) i get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Assessment_1",
    "created_at": "2020-04-01T17:29:50.528Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-01T17:29:50.528Z",
    "risk_value": "3.92156862745098"
  },
  ...
]
```

2) I don't understand how to delete `created_at` and `updated_at` from result.

**app/models/assessment.rb**

```
scope :with_assessment_progresses, ->(customer_id) {
  joins(Arel.sql("LEFT JOIN assessment_progresses ON (assessment_progresses.assessment_id = assessments.id AND assessment_progresses.customer_id = #{customer_id})")).
  select("assessments.*, assessment_progresses.risk_value")
}
```

**spec/models/assessment_spec.rb**

```
describe "Method 'with_assessment_progresses'" do
  let!(:admin)                     { create(:admin) }
    let!(:customer)                { create(:customer, created_by: admin.id) }
  let!(:assessment)                { create(:assessment) }
    let!(:assessment_progress_1)   { create(:assessment_progress, customer_id: customer.id, assessment_id: assessment.id, risk_value: 3.812) }

  it "return assessments with risk_value for customer" do
    assessment_with_risk = Assessment.with_assessment_progresses(customer.id)

    assessment_with_risk.delete("created_at")
    assessment_with_risk.delete("updated_at")

    expect(assessment_with_risk.length).to eq(1)
    expect(assessment_with_risk).to eq(
      [
        {
          "id"=> assessment.id,
          "name"=> assessment.name,
          "risk_value"=> assessment_progress_1.risk_value
        }
      ]
    )

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
.select("assessments.*, assessment_progresses.risk_value")
```

`created_at` and `updatet_at` come from the `assessements.*`, these columns automatically get generated for active record models. If you only want certain values, the just select only those

```
.select("assessments.id, assessments.name ,assessment_progresses.risk_value")
```

Comment: I need in response created_at and updated_at, but in rspec i need to delete them

Comment: @Ants_soo Glad you figured it out. However, why would you remove elements in your specs before testing them. If you don't want to test them, then it is better to just check if the values are included where you want them, see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issues:

```
Assessment.with_assessment_progresses(customer.id).as_json
```

And i delete timestamps using:

```
object.each{ |h| h.delete("updated_at") && h.delete("created_at")}
```